# I need comparate this column with a variable for update a table

Tags: oracle

I need comparate this column with a variable for update a table, i have this query:

```
declare v_IdMig int;
begin
select max(ID_Mig)
      into v_IdMig
      from MIGPT021_LOG;

update MIGPT021_LOG
set RegPostMig = (select sum(cantidad) CantidadReg
from
(
select count(*) cantidad, sysdate FechaHora from CRPDTA.F59PT021
union all
select count(*) cantidad, sysdate FechaHora from CRPDTA.F59PT021_HTR)),
FecPostReg = (select max(FechaHora) Fecha
from
(
select count(*) cantidad, sysdate FechaHora from CRPDTA.F59PT021
union all
select count(*) cantidad, sysdate FechaHora from CRPDTA.F59PT021_HTR))
where max(Id_Mig) = v_IdMig;
```

But i have this error:

ORA-06550: línea 20, columna 7:
PL/SQL: ORA-00934: función de grupo no permitida aquí
ORA-06550: línea 7, columna 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: línea 20, columna 28:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
 <a double-quote
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Thank you

Comment: you are missing an END; at the end of your block

Answer (score 1):

```
ORA-00934: función de grupo no permitida aquí
```

You cannot use a group function (such as MAX) in the WHERE clause, as you are trying to do here:

```
where max(Id_Mig) = v_IdMig;
```

I think you simply want:

```
where Id_Mig = v_IdMig;
```

You've selected the maximum value already.  I presume you then want to update the row that has that value.